# How to change the spatial complexity of DP of binomial coefficient to O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is the Dynamic Programming algorithm.

```
int bin2(int n, int k){
        index i, j;
        i tn B[0 ][0 k] B[0..n][0..k]; i
            for(i=0; i <= n; i++)
                for(j=0; j <= minimum(i,k); j++)
                    if (j 0 || j i) [i][j] 1
                        i
                        if (j==0 || j==i) B[i][j] = 1;
                        else B[i][j] = B[i-1][j-1] + B[i-1][j];
                        return B[n][k];
    }
```

Its spatial complexity is O(n^2).
Can this be lowered to O(n)?
What should I do if I can use the property that 'when the calculation of a row is finished, the previously calculated value is not needed'?
In the code above, I got a hint that you can change k to 1 and j to j%2. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused with your code, which seems to have several typos, but here is how you can evaluate {n \choose k} in linear spatial complexity, using the fact that {n \choose k} = (n!)/(k!*(n-k)!) is the k-th element of the n-th row of Pascal's triangle (which you seem to already know, I am just making sure it's out here).

```cpp
int nchoosek(int n, int k)
{
  int i, j; //These are indices of the row and column respectively
  int oldrow [n+1], newrow [n+1]; //n+1 is the largest size of a row we will need.
  //we will be computing a row of Pascal's triangle based on the previous row,
  //then swapping the two.
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) //we iterate over the rows
  {
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) //we iterate over the elements in a row, there are i+1 elements in row i, thus n+1 elements in row n.
    {
      if (j == 0 || j == i)
        newrow[j] = 1; //we set the first and last element of a row to 1.
      else
        newrow[j] = oldrow[j-1] + oldrow[j]; //we set the other elements to the sum of the two elements above them in Pascal's triangle.
    }
    swap(oldrow, newrow); //we swap the two arrays, and will now be counting the next row, using the row which we just counted.
  }
  //the i-th row of Pascal's triangle will always end up in the oldrow array
  return oldrow[k]; //we return its k-th element.
}
```

Comment: This requires two arrays. Check out the first method I posted to bring it down to only 1 array.

Comment: That's true. I know that method, I just thought that making it more clearly simulate the computation of Pascal's triangle would make a bit more sense, since OP is clearly learning fundamental algorithmics. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

The key is this line

```
B[i][j] = B[i-1][j-1] + B[i-1][j];
```

You see that, for the current state, we are dependent on `i-1` and `j-1`. We don't need all of the previous rows, just the `i-1`th row.

**Method 1**

You should be looking to change it to something like

```
B[j] += B[j - 1];
```

Keep overwriting the same 1D array i.e iterating over `j` for each `i`.

Try solving it by yourself. If you still want to look at the solution, it is at the end of my answer.

**Method 2**

Some people like to keep two rows one for earlier and one for current one. They alternate between `0`th row and `1`st row by using `mod`. `(i+1) % 2` will give `1` when `i = 0` and `0` when `i = 1`. But this method uses two arrays instead of one as shown in method one.

**Method 3**

Similar to method 2. Some people keep two arrays previous and current. They swap the whole array instead of changing which array is the current one to fill. The swap happens after the `j` loop and inside the `i` loop. Refer the solution by @Maurycyt for this method.

**Efficiency wise:** Method 1 > Method 2 > Method 3

**Solution with Method 1:**

```
int binomialCoeff(int n, int k) 
{ 
    vector<int> dp(k+1, 0);

    dp[0] = 1;
  
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j = min(i, k); j > 0; j--) 
            dp[j] += dp[j-1]; 
    } 
    return dp[k]; 
}
```